# Can I link to another source file with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I know that in Doxygen I can link to another function using the @see command. Is it possible to link to another source file? For instance, lets say I have two source files which communicate with one another: a manager and a plugin (or something along those lines), and I want to reference the manager in the 'brief' of the plugin, what would that look like?

Comment: You can use \ref or \link (with a closing \endlink).

Comment: @YanikCrépeau What's the difference between using the ```@``` symbol and using the ```/``` symbol? For instance, if I start the block like this: ```/*!``` then i can use ```/ref``` but if i start it like this: ```/**``` then I can't, why is that? One seems to want me to use the ```@``` symbol and the other the ```/``` symbol.

Comment: It’s the same thing.  dOxygen is agnostic regarding the underlying language of programmation.  Originally it used the backslash notation but after the release of javadoc (circa 1998) where the @ sign were the norm, dOxygen started to support the @ notation as well.

Comment: You can never use `/ref` but it should always be possible to  use `\ref` or `@ref`, i.e. independent of of the use of `/**` or `/*!`, in case this is not the case can you provide an example plus the doxygen version you are using?

Comment: Regarding linking, one can always add the `\anchor` to a source file and refer to the label of this anchor.

Comment: @albert Ah, I see what the problem was. It was my mistake then I was attempting to use the ```/``` rather than the ```\```; hence why it wasn't working.